# RxJava collect emitted values to array

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

How can I collect emitted values from observable to array?

**Input:**

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

**Expected output:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: `Observable.just(arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))`?

Comment: use `.toList()`. Observable.just(1,2,3,4,..).toList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of options. Easiest is to use `toList()`:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    .toList()
```

If you need to do more than just collect them into a list you can use `collect()`:

```
List<Integer> collected = new ArrayList<>();
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    .collect(collected, (alreadyCollected, value) -> {
             // Do something with value and add it to collected at the end
        });
```

[Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#collect) you'll find a better explanation about `collect`